# Depth First Search & Breadth First Search

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a depth first search and breadth first search for our n-ary tree.

```
std::vector<char> element;
Tree* firstChild;
Tree* nextSibling;
Tree* parent;
```

These are the private members of my Tree class. I wrote a print function that prints element of the vector member and I tried to print all elements DFS and BFS. I call the function for the root node but I got segmentation fault error. Can you help me?

Comment: The code you haven't shown has an error.

Comment: also you will probably need a boolean field for visited or at least a reliable way to identify if each node has been visited by your searches.

Comment: OK. I'll do it. Thank you

Comment: Use a separate structure for tracking visited status, adding it to the tree itself is ugly.

Comment: If you're still having trouble, we need a little more code to work with to help you out.